# These [ajax-*] tags should be synonyms of [ajax]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, status-declined, tags, synonym-request

These tags should be synonyms of [ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajax):

1. [ajax-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajax-request) => Questions: 118 Closed: 1
2. [ajaxtags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajaxtags) => Questions: 4
3. [ajax-success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajax-success) => Questions: 21

The request for these tags to be synonyms is already submitted. If you have the required privileges and know enough about [ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajax) then be sure to vote on the synonyms [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ajax/synonyms)

Answer (score 9):

[AjaxTags](http://ajaxtags.sourceforge.net) is a specific library. I think it is distinct enough from [ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajax) to not be merged with it.